How do I create circle around navigation arrow like this?
How do I create circle around navigation arrow like this in WordPress what's setting or code 

I'm trying to add some CSS code at Custom CSS in WordPress but it's not working, and I'm looking for any setting for this, but I can't find out.
This is what I can do.

What have you tried so far? What is not working as expected?

All you really need is border-radius: 100% to make the button round. The icon at the can be horizontally and vertically centered with flexbox.


button {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: brown;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: none;
}
<button>&lt</button>




Thank you very much. Where do I put this code?

it is HTML and CSS code. You need some kind of basic knowledge of both. Completely depends on the rest of the code.

I'm curious about your use of Flexbox when the result is the same without it.

@TimR in this specific case it seems to be the same result because the icon is larger than the box (due to the border radius). You need it as soon as the icon is smaller than the box.
